# How to display component using forEach in ReactJS Application

Tags: reactjs

How can I display my product.colors ? I need to parse them first that's why I'm trying with forEach somehow:

Here is what I tryed:

```
    const ParsedColors = props => {
            return(
            props.product.color.forEach(col => {
                const parsed = JSON.parse(col)
                return(
                    <button name="color" value={parsed.value} style={{backgroundColor: `${parsed.value}`}} onClick={() => colorPicker([props.product._id, parsed.value])}/>
                )
            })
            )
        }
...

<div>
    <ParsedColors product={product}/>
<div/>
```

I know that forEach isn't returning an array but I can't find a way to do it in map. As I said, I need to parse each color

This returns an err:

> Error: ParsedColors(...): Nothing was returned from render. This
> usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing,
> return null.

Comment: forEach doesn't return anything. You need to use map if you want to assign the iteration change to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` returns nothing so you cannot assign a variable to it the way you are doing it.
Use map instead

```
const ParsedColors = props => {
            return(
            props.product.color.map(col => {
                const parsed = JSON.parse(col)
                return(
                    <button name="color" value={parsed.value} style={{backgroundColor: `${parsed.value}`}} onClick={() => colorPicker([props.product._id, parsed.value])}/>
                )
            })
            )
        }
...
```